# Meanings of っこなし

Tags: meaning, expressions

**How many meanings does っこなし have?**

On the one hand, I've seen in jisho and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6836/what-does-%E9%80%83%E3%81%92%E3%81%A3%E3%81%93%E3%81%AA%E3%81%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86-mean) that っこなし is a variant of っこない, which means "no chance of; no way that; certainly not; will never happen".

However, the usages I've found for っこなし seem to differ in meaning.

In these sentences:

> そんなつらいこと言っこなし。
> 固いこと言いっこなし。
> 細かいことは言いっこなしだよ。

**Would っこなし have the function/meaning of an negative imperative (Don't say ...)?**

And in this sentence:

> 誰が勝っても、恨みっこなしね。

I know by jisho that 恨みっこなし means "with no hard feelings", but **if translated literally, what would っこなし mean here?**

**Besides, is there another case where っこなし would have another different meaning** apart from 1) "no chance of; no way that; certainly not; will never happen", 2) "Don't ..." (negative imperative) and 3) 恨みっこなし?

Comment: Imperatives are *generally* implied in Japanese, and an imperative sense has to be gleaned from context. Even if we say something like 「〜してください」 - notice we *don't* say 「〜してくだされ」.

Comment: It’d be easier to understand if you add お互いに〜.   誰が勝ってもお互いに恨みっこなし。whoever wins no hard feelings for each other.   It’s not “no chance” that you mentioned. できっこない (できるわけがない)

Comment: But then, if you confirm thay っこなし does not mean "no chance" in my examples as I already suspected, then whay does it mean? And if it does not mean either a negative imperative, from which meaning is then the negative imperative implied?

Comment: As commented, it's mostly the implication that makes it an imperative. Compare English *No hard feelings*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, "No smoking" is grammatically not an imperative, but it effectively has such a meaning ("Don't smoke").

Likewise, ～なし is grammatically not an imperative (it's just "No ～"), but depending on the context, it can be interpreted as a (negative) imperative ("Don't ～"). Although っこ and なし are often paired together, なし by itself can effectively mean "Don't".

- それ以上はなしだ。 No more. / Don't ask more.
- 反論はナシですよ。 No rebuttals please. / Don't argue back.

Besides, ～っこなし is not necessarily a negative imperative, either. For example, 勝てっこなしだよ means "There is no chance of winning" rather than "Let's not win".

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Now I understand the meaning of っこなし and the interpretation of it as a negative imperative.